# Give an example of a function $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow$ $\mathbb R$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ but not continuous at $0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Give an example of a function $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow$ $\mathbb R$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ but not continuous at $0$

Comment: I can find examples where the derivative itself is not continuous at 0, but nothing where the function is not continuous at 0. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no such function. A function must be continuous at a point to be differentiable there.

Comment: $f$ is differentiable at $x_0 \Rightarrow f$ is  continuous at $x_0$

Comment: Are you sure you reported correctly the exercise? It is a very basic and important fact that a function is continuous at all points where it is differentiable.

Comment: There is a standard example function that is differentiable, but whose _derivative_ is discontinuous. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I stated the exercise correctly, looks like it turns out to be a trick question! I agree that no such function exists. Glad I wasn't going crazy, haha